# Deferred assignment in makefile with one round of expansion

Tags: makefile

This may be a very esoteric question, but it's a larger problem that boils down to this. There is a global variable keeping track of state (in this case it's `NUM`), that is changing. The problem is I need to do a *deferred* assignment (to `LIST`) but I need the *current* value of `NUM` to be expanded.

```
NUM := ONE

LIST = three four $(VAR_$(NUM))

NUM := TWO

VAR_ONE := SUCCESS
VAR_TWO := FAILURE

$(info LIST => $(LIST))
$(info LIST VALUE => $(value LIST) )
```

This results in:

```
LIST => three four FAILURE
LIST VALUE => three four $(VAR_$(NUM))
```

What I would like to see:

```
LIST => three four SUCCESS
LIST VALUE => three four $(VAR_ONE)
```

I have a very cumbersome solution, which I'll post below, but if there is a simpler solution I would be glad to hear it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My (pretty ugly) solution is to use a macro to construct the assignment, to force one round of expansion:

```
define append_deferred
$(1) += $(2)
endef

NUM := ONE

LIST = three four
$(eval $(call append_deferred,LIST,$$(VAR_$(NUM))))

NUM := TWO

VAR_ONE := SUCCESS
VAR_TWO := FAILURE

$(info LIST == $(LIST))
$(info LIST VALUE == $(value LIST) )
```

This prints the desired result:

```
LIST => three four SUCCESS
LIST VALUE => three four $(VAR_ONE)
```

But I'm wondering if there is a better way.